# $store.state needs page reload to update Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I'm doing a single login and, after the response, the menu header is updated and it should show the user's name.

The menu changes as expected, but the user's name isn't show until reload the page by myself (F5).

This is my code:

Login.vue

```
....
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            type: 1
        }
    },
    methods: {
        login() {
            this.$store.dispatch('retrieveToken', {
                email: this.email,
                password: this.password,
                type: this.type
            })
            .then(response => {
                this.$router.push({name: 'search'});
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(errorMessage);
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        user_id: localStorage.getItem('user_id') || null,
        fname: localStorage.getItem('fname') || null,
        lname: localStorage.getItem('lname') || null,
        email: localStorage.getItem('email') || null,
        type: localStorage.getItem('type') || null,
        token: localStorage.getItem('token') || null
    },
    getters: {
        loggedIn(state) {
            return (state.token == null) ? false : true
        },
        isCustomer(state) {
            return (state.type == 1) ? true : false
        },
        isPartner(state) {
            return (state.type == 2) ? true : false
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        retrieveToken(state, data) {
            state.user_id = data.user_id
            state.fname = data.name
            state.lname = data.name
            state.email = data.email
            state.type = data.type
            state.token = data.access_token
        }
    },
    actions: {
        retrieveToken(context, credentials) {
            let userData = []
            let userCredentials = {
                user_credencial: {
                    email : credentials.email,
                    password: credentials.password,
                    type : credentials.type
                }
            }

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                axios.post(process.env.VUE_APP_API_AUTH, userCredentials)
                .then(response => { // Credentials resolved
                    let user_id = response.data.objeto.user.id_user,
                        fname = response.data.objeto.profile.f_name,
                        lname = response.data.objeto.profile.l_name,
                        // type = response.data.objeto.user.type,
                        token = response.data.objeto.access_token.token;

                    // Storing Auth data
                    userData.user_id = user_id
                    userData.fname = fname
                    userData.lname = lname
                    userData.type = credentials.type
                    userData.email = credentials.email
                    userData.access_token = token

                    localStorage.setItem('user_id', userData.user_id)
                    localStorage.setItem('fname', userData.fname)
                    localStorage.setItem('lname', userData.lname)
                    localStorage.setItem('email', userData.email)
                    localStorage.setItem('type', userData.type)
                    localStorage.setItem('access_token', userData.access_token)

                    context.commit('retrieveToken', userData)
                    return resolve(response)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    return reject(error)
                })
            })

        }
    }
})
```

And finally the Header.vue

```
<ul v-if="isPartner">
  <base-dropdown tag="li">
    <span slot="title">¡Hola, <strong class="text-primary">{{this.$store.state.fname}}</strong>!</span>
  </base-dropdown>
</ul>

<script>
export default {
    computed: {
        isCustomer() {
            return this.$store.getters.isCustomer
        },
        isPartner() {
            return this.$store.getters.isPartner
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Also, i tried to make a computed function in Header.vue called loggedName to retrieve the user's name just like i did with isCustomer and isPartner (to change the showed menu) but i had the same result: needed F5 to show the user's name on menu.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `retrieveToken` mutation, you're setting the `state` object's `fname` and `lname` properties both to `data.name`, which you never define anywhere:

```
retrieveToken(state, data) {
  state.user_id = data.user_id
  state.fname = data.name
  state.lname = data.name
  state.email = data.email
  state.type = data.type
  state.token = data.access_token
}
```

I think you just want to set them to `data.fname` and `data.lname` respectively.